# Send e-mail/webhook call on successful pipeline completion

Tags: gitlab, continuous-delivery

We use Gitlab for source control and CI/CD.

I'd like to notify our testers that our application has been updated in a test environment when a pipeline on a specific branch completes successfully.

**The criteria for this is that I only want to send an e-mail/call a webhook if a pipeline a) completes successfully and b) is on a specific branch.**

Our CI/CD pipelines tend to have the following stages:

```
stages:
 - setup
 - compliance
 - test
 - build
 - deploy
```

An example of one of the parts of our `build` stage for example is:

```
build-master:
  image: docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u $DEV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER -p $DEV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PW $DEV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST
    - docker build --pull --build-arg HG_APP_DEPLOY_KEY="$HG_APP_DEPLOY_KEY" -t $DEV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:stable .
    - docker push $DEV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
  only:
    - master
```

I'm trying to investigate a way to add a final stage, something like `notify`, which sends an e-mail (or calls a webhook) to one of our Microsoft Teams channels. This is easy enough to set up on Teams, so I don't need to worry about that end.

I've investigated a few **Integrations** options on Gitlab. You can set up a *Teams* integration for example, or an *E-mail on Push* integration. **None of these are sufficient however** because they don't allow me to filter **only pipelines which are a) successful and b) on a specific branch**.

I've also investigated the **Webhooks** option on Gitlab but this doesn't work with Teams - I get a `400 error summary text required` which appears to be insurmountable (as there's no ability to add such a summary from the Webhooks UI).

Presuming therefore that I can't use Gitlab's UI features (happy to accept an answer on this however if we can meet the above criteria), I'm now considering how I can potentially use Docker, like we do in other parts of the pipeline, to send an e-mail or call a webhook.

What would be the quickest/easiest/**least number of lines** way of doing this in a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite sure that there's a `curl` on board the `docker` image used by the `build-master` stage. So, some external email service like [sendgrid.com](https://sendgrid.com) could be called in the last line of `build-master`

```
...
- docker push $DEV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
- curl --request POST \
   --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \ ...
```

This would be the solution with the *least lines of code*.

If there's no `curl` in the docker image I suggest a new stage:

```
notify_team:
  image: ruby:2.1
  stage: notify
  script:
    - curl --request POST 
        --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send ...
  only: master
```

Comment: Bingo - worked a treat. Thanks! Will award bounty tomorrow.

Comment: Not really a solution to send email rather to send a web request.